# Random value procent progressbar VB.Net

Tags: vb.net

I want to divide 4 progress bar, depending on the first progress bar, all assembled value to give the value of 100. If the first progress bar, the random value will start from (45,100), if the value is 45, then the other progress bar values Random will be progressbar2 = 15, progressbar=3 15, or progressbar 25 and so on. (that's one example). the value of the randomization of the three remaining progress bars + add to the first value, must give 100.

If Progressbar1 = 75, the other 3 progressbar value sum = 25. 75+25=100. 
Example: Progressbar2= 10, progressbar3=10 and progressbar4=5 .

```
 If LBPublic.Text = ("1") Then
            If AnswerA.Location = New Point(LocationA) Then
                Dim R As New Random
                Dim value As Integer
                value = R.Next(45, 100)
                ProgressBar1.Value += value
                LbProcentA.Text = ProgressBar1.Value
                Dim R1 As New Random
                Dim value1 As Integer
                value1 = R.Next(0, value)
                ProgressBar2.Value += value1
                LbProcentB.Text = ProgressBar2.Value
            End If
        End If
```

I do not really get out doing this. I note progress bars with (progressbar1, progressbar2, progressbar3, and progressbar4.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
Private R As New Random

Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    ProgressBar1.Value = R.Next(45, 101) ' min of 45, max of 100
    ProgressBar2.Value = R.Next(101 - ProgressBar1.Value)
    ProgressBar3.Value = R.Next(101 - (ProgressBar1.Value + ProgressBar2.Value))
    ProgressBar4.Value = 100 - (ProgressBar1.Value + ProgressBar2.Value + ProgressBar3.Value)

    Debug.Print("ProgressBar1: " & ProgressBar1.Value)
    Debug.Print("ProgressBar2: " & ProgressBar2.Value)
    Debug.Print("ProgressBar3: " & ProgressBar3.Value)
    Debug.Print("ProgressBar4: " & ProgressBar4.Value)
    Debug.Print("Total: " & (ProgressBar1.Value + ProgressBar2.Value + ProgressBar3.Value + ProgressBar4.Value))
End Sub
```